# Conducting a meta-analysis of proportions and one proportion is negative

Tags: data-transformation, meta-analysis, proportion, metafor

I am conducting a meta-analysis of proportions and plan to first use the Freeman-Tukey double arcsine transformation before meta-analysing the data. However, one of the proportions is negative (-1.3%). (For context, this is because it is a proportion of an association mediated and the direct and indirect effects have opposite directions.) Because the proportion is negative, when I try to transform it with the double arcsine transformation (using the *metafor* package), it is converted to NaN. I have 2 questions:

1. Is it appropriate to convert this negative proportion to zero for inclusion in the meta-analysis? I think excluding it might bias the results.
2. I noticed that when I converted it to zero and conducted a meta-analysis, the back-transformed meta-analytic proportion differed quite a bit to the mean of the raw proportions. The difference between the back-transformed meta-analytic proportion vs the mean of the raw proportions was smaller when I converted the negative proportion to a larger value (0.05) compared to when I converted it to zero. I therefore wondered if it is a bad idea to convert to zero?

I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please say more about how you got a "raw proportion" that is negative. Some types of probability models might return a negative _predicted_ probability, but a "raw proportion" is usually the number of positive cases divided by the total number of cases, so it's necessarily between 0 and 1.

Comment: @EdM thanks. I have provided context in the description (it is a proportion of an association mediated).

Comment: You might add +1.3% to all study proportions, perform meta-analysis, and then reduce by -1.3% all results...

Comment: @Joe_74 that's a nice idea, thanks!

Comment: @GiuseppeBiondi-Zoccai, apologies for the late follow-up on this, but how would you suggest I obtain standard error / CIs? Shall I use SE from meta-analysis (of estimates with 1.3% added) and derive CIs by doing (meta-analytic estimate - 1.3) -/+ 1.96 * meta_analyticSE? Thank you!